# C Pointers with 2D arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

First off I want to see if I get the basic concepts right,

So when an array is created, say, int arr[10], the ten elements are placed in memory contiguously. Now if I create a pointer to that array using int *ar = arr; then I can refer it using *(ar+i). Where i is the element I want to refer. Makes sense.

Now coming to my doubt, if the same thing is done with two dimensional array, say, arr[10][10]. Even though its two dimensional the elements are still placed contiguously in memory, row after row.Assume I do int *ar = arr. Now if I want to refer row i, I do *(ar+i).

Why is this? Shouldn't it go the ith element of the same row?, as before?

Comment: The correct term is "contiguously", not "linearly". Contiguous means "packed with no gaps".

Comment: If anyone can find a more canonical duplicate and link it, feel free to do so. This question is somewhat frequently asked.